# Is there a calculable correlation between RAM storage capacity and number of pins?

Tags: memory

For example, there are 30-pin and 72-pin SIMMs, which are 32 bits wide.

But, 64-bit wide DIMMs might come in 168-pin or 184-pin variants.

How can one calculate the number of pins a specific type of RAM stick might have, based on its storage capacity or other factors, other than through simple memorization? Is it even possible/worth the hassle?

**EDIT**

For example, is there a way to deduce this:

This stick of RAM is of type *X* (be it a DIMM, SIMM, etc.)

It is *N* bits wide.

Therefore, the possible pin counts are *A, B, C,* and *D*.

Comment: It's not worth the hassle as it really means nothing.  In over 15 years of building computers it never came up once, as there are standards in place. If it's going to fit and work, it has the right number of connectors.  Also keep in mind that just because there's X number of connectors available on the form factor they used for the RAM modules, doesn't mean they're all being used.  What computer problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, thanks for the comment. Not trying to solve a specific computer problem per-se, but I'm reading through an old A+ book, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the decisions that were made to give certain types of RAM sticks certain pin counts. Almost seems like the pin counts are random (e.g., why 30 and 72?), although each pin is clearly there because it serves a specific purpose.

Comment: Can you include an extract from the book.

Answer (score 1):

If you measure over enough generations of Ram, then yes, But correlation is not causation: Higher memory is not caused by high pin count, and high pin count is not caused by high memory capacity.

However innovation happens in time (see moore's law), so time is a cause of high bus width and therefore high pin count, and also a cause of high memory capacity. And then some innovation comes along and the chip manufactures decide that because of clock skew that they should serialise the bus, this for a time reduces pin count, but then they start adding multiple serial buses.

So yes while you may find a correlation, remember correlation is not causation, it is not even as simple as y=mx+c, it is statistics.

As an example I look at the flash devices on my desk usb 256MB, usb2GB, usb8GB, sd2GB, sb4GB, mmc64MB, mmc156MB, the sd cards have 9 pins, the mmc 15pins, the usb4. but is there a connection between pins and capacity, NO. Newer ones have higher capacity, MMCs are small because I don't use them anymore so don't have any new ones, one of the usb is small because it is old, not because it only has 4 pins.

Comment: This makes sense. So I assume then that manufacturers of RAM sticks and motherboards just kind of developed their products, and by knowing each others' standards, just figured out that X pin count would work well in a slot of Y motherboard?

Comment: @JoshBeam It is not a matter of pins. there are standards: pin 1 does this, pin 2 does that, distance between pins is this, timing sequences are that, voltages are bla etc. Everything has to be correct for it to work. You can't just say I see that board has 100 pins, “Hey you, can you make me a RAM with 100 pins.” e.g. Look at the power socket on my wall, it has 3 pins. Can I plug in any appliance needing 3 pin power. No, it provides 240V at 50Hz, earth, live and neutral. If I connect something only excepting 120V I will break it. But with an adapter I can connect something needing 2 pins.